# CollectionView Touch is now working when placed on top of tabBar Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicollectionview, uitabbar

I have added a collectionView on top of a UITabBar but its touch is not working.[The screeshot for the tabBar and collectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3F3w.jpg)

The code is attached below, I want the collectionView to be touchable. Here quickAccessView is the UIView that contains the collectionView. For constraints I'm using snapKit

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        self.tabBar.bringSubviewToFront(quickAccessView)
    }

    private func setupQuickAccessView(){
        print("this is tabBar's height", self.tabBar.frame.size.height)
        self.tabBar.frame.size.height = 150
        print("this is new tabBar's height", self.tabBar.frame.size.height)
        self.tabBar.addSubview(quickAccessView)
        quickAccessView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    private func addQuickAccessViewConstraints(){
        quickAccessView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.right.left.equalTo(self.tabBar.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
            make.height.equalTo(76)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.tabBar.snp.bottom).offset(-80)
        }
    }
```

this is after modification that Aman told
The UITabBarController

```
final class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {
   private lazy var quickAccessView: QuickAccessView = .fromNib()
    var quickAccessSupportedTabBar: QuickAccessSupportedTabBar {
        self.tabBar as! QuickAccessSupportedTabBar // Even code is crashing here
    }
    // Even code is crashing here
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBar.backgroundColor = .white
        
}
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.view.frame = self.quickAccessView.bounds
        setupUI()
    }
}

extension MainTabBarController{
    
    private func setupUI(){
        setupQuickAcessView()
        addQuickAcessViewConstraints()
    }
    
}

// MARK: - Setting Up Quick Access view

extension MainTabBarController {
    private func setupQuickAcessView(){

        self.quickAccessSupportedTabBar.addSubview(quickAccessView)
    }
    
    private func addQuickAcessViewConstraints(){
        quickAccessView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.right.equalTo(self.quickAccessSupportedTabBar.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
            make.height.equalTo(66)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.quickAccessSupportedTabBar.snp.top)
        }
    }
}
```

the UItabBar and here it is throwing error and I too am confuse that how to access it and convert it to points

```
class QuickAccessSupportedTabBar: UITabBar {
    override public func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // if `quickAccessView` is visible, then convert `point` to its coordinate-system
        // and check if it is within its bounds; if it is, then ask `quickAccessView`
        // to perform the hit-test; you may skip the `isHidden` check, in-case this view
        // is always present in your app; I'm assuming based on your screenshot that
        // the user can dismiss / hide the `quickAccessView` using the cross icon

        if !quickAccessView.isHidden {
            // Convert the point to the target view's coordinate system.
            // The target view isn't necessarily the immediate subview

            let targetPoint = quickAccessView.convert(point, from: self)
            
            if quickAccessView.bounds.contains(targetPoint) {

                // The target view may have its view hierarchy, so call its
                // hitTest method to return the right hit-test view
                return quickAccessView.hitTest(targetPoint, with: event)
            }
        }
        
        // else execute tabbar's default implementation
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: [why are you duplicating question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75156020/how-to-make-a-tappable-uiview-on-top-of-tabbar-swift). Edit the old and put code there...

Comment: @FahimParkar that one I had deleted, this show more details

Comment: @FahimParkar As you told to increase the border, I think the code above is what you told please look into it and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what may be happening here is that since you've added `quickAccessView` as tab bar's subview, it is not accepting touches. This would be so because the tabbar's hist test will fail in this scenario.

To get around this, instead of using a UITabBar, subclass UITabBar, let us call it `ToastyTabBar` for reference. See the code below:

```swift
class ToastyTabBar: UITabBar {
    override public func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // if `quickAccessView` is visible, then convert `point` to its coordinate-system
        // and check if it is within its bounds; if it is, then ask `quickAccessView`
        // to perform the hit-test; you may skip the `isHidden` check, in-case this view
        // is always present in your app; I'm assuming based on your screenshot that
        // the user can dismiss / hide the `quickAccessView` using the cross icon

        if !quickAccessView.isHidden {
            // Convert the point to the target view's coordinate system.
            // The target view isn't necessarily the immediate subview

            let targetPoint = quickAccessView.convert(point, from: self)
            
            if quickAccessView.bounds.contains(targetPoint) {

                // The target view may have its view hierarchy, so call its
                // hitTest method to return the right hit-test view
                return quickAccessView.hitTest(targetPoint, with: event)
            }
        }
        
        // else execute tabbar's default implementation
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}
```

Set this as the class of your `tabBar` (both in the storyboard and the swift file), and then see if that solves it for you.
You'll have to figure out a way to make `quickAccessView` accessible to the tabbar for the hit test check. I haven't advised on that above because I'm not familiar with your class hierarchy, and how and where you set stuff up, but this should be trivial.

If this solves it for you, please consider marking this as the answer, and if it does not then please share a little more info here about where you're having the problem.

**Edit (for someone using a `UITabBarController`):**

In response to your comment about "how to access UITabBar class from UITabBarController" here's how I would go about it.

I'm assuming you have a storyboard with the `UITabBarController`.

The first step (ignore this step if you already have a `UITabBarController` custom subclass) is that you need to subclass `UITabBarController`. Let us call this class `ToastyTabBarController` for reference. Set this class on the `UITabBarController` in your storyboard using the identity inspector pane in xcode.

The second step is to set the class of the `UITabBar` in your storyboard as `ToastyTabBar` (feel free to name it something more 'professional' ).

This is to be done in the same storyboard, in your `UITabBarController` scene itself. It will show the tabBar under your `UITabBarController`, and you can set the custom class on it using the identity inspector pane just like earlier.

The next step is to expose a computed property on your custom `UITabBarController` class, as shown below.

```swift
var toastyTabBar: ToastyTabBar {
    self.tabBar as! ToastyTabBar 
}
```

And that's it. Now you have a property on your UITabBarController subclass which is of `ToastyTabBar` type and you can use this new property, `toastyTabBar`, however you require.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you please tell how to access UITabBar class from UITabBarController, Because, I'm using UITabBarController

Comment: @RohanDalmotra - I've edited my answer to describe how to go about it when using a `UITabBarController`. Let me know if this helps. If you need further help or are not clear about it, feel free to ask and I can quickly create a sample project on github.

Comment: can you please create the sample project? this would mean the world to me

Comment: I'm using the quickAccessView in tabBarController but how can I use hottest in UITabBar, And how to convert it into point

Comment: I have upgraded the question above. please help if you know the solution

Comment: I've been a bit busy @RohanDalmotra. I'll try to have create a sample and upload it to github in a couple of days.